# вывод данных form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <pre><form id="theForm" action="cpa.php" method="POST">
                     <input type="radio" name="r1" value="1">Визиты<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="r1" value="2">Заявки<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="r1" value="3">Договора<br>
                     <input type="radio" name="r1" value="4">Контрольные оплаты<br>
                     <button type="submit">Проверить, какой из элементов выбран</button>
                         </form> </pre>
                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                           $("#theForm").submit(function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault(); 

  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(), 
    success: function(data) {
      
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      
    }
  });


});
```

как вытащить значение с form data ? пытаюсь так `if ($_POST['r1'] == 1)` не получается

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вытащить данные на клиенте или сервере?

Comment: на сервере.....

Comment: Тогда тут javascript и jquery вообще никакого значения не имеют)

Comment: приведите свой код которым пытаетесь получить данные, чтобы ответить почему это не получается. посмотрите в инструментах разработчика что вообще отправляет клиент на сервер. попробуйте отправить то что считаете нужным, изменив данные и посмотрите ответ сервера во всех случаях. даже для начинающих это очень хороший инструмент и помогает решить много проблем. после того как получите результаты и не сможете найти ответ, обновите вопрос, дополнив его результатом. таким образом будет возможность реально Вам помочь, а не выстраивать цепочку предположений даже не видя кода.